# Click Drag Function Maya Python

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to write my 1St Maya Python Script......I know I have a ways to go before I don't keep getting dozens of Syntax Errors....But it's a simple script with no UI, and any even tidbits or clues I can get to get it to work will set me off with scripting.

Just a simple fuction of 'Clicking and dragging' visibilities on or off of the Display Layer boxes..the main function I am trying to define is:

draggerContext?
or
cmds.selectPref(clickBoxSize=True)

how to implement the fuction on/off..
any clues would be of help as the trickiest part of this script is defining the Function of CLick Drag select...

Thanks

my script that does not work yet:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

#Click and drag to Turn On/Off Visibilities of the Display Layers

draggerContext_id = "dga"
def dga():
    cmds.selectPref(clickBoxSize=True)
    cmds.selectcmds.selectPref(clickBoxSize=True)
    if:
         clickdragBoxSize.sel=True(layerEditorLayerButtonVisibilityChange):
         cmds.selectPref(clickBoxSize=True)
    else:
         cmds.select(layerEditorLayerButtonVisibilityChange=True)

SelectLayerEditorButtonVisibility()
```

Comment: have you an exemple of the action you want to create. I don't understand what you are dragging on what. Why not using simple setAttr visibility ?

Comment: yes, the example is simply hovering our mouse pointer on top of the visibility boxes and dragging down or up turn on or off their visibilities (quickly check or uncheck those boxes) similiar to adobe photshop layers function, but I would like to add functionality into Maya.

Comment: I will try setAttr visibility=True.....but the main challenge is defining the 'ClickDrag' I think..?

Comment: I know it is the Dragger context...just having difficulty with calling the drag procedure..